# How can I create own Bluetooth RGB Controller app for android and ios using phonegap or ionic?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth

I'm currently doing home lighting system using Arduino and LED Strip and Android Phone. But I don't want to use other app from store. I want to create my own Android to make Bluetooth RGB Controller app using ionic or phonegap. I can't find the tutorial on googling. Please guide me and help me. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's the most easy way that u use ""APP Inventor2"" to build ur own app